# how to use fullcalender properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, calendar, fullcalendar

I apply jQuery plugin fullcalender and the result isn't as expected. I still don't know how to render information as required inside days' blocks. the events show colored boxes but empty from needed information. it should displays title and description of events.

ASP.NET CORE INTITY

```
public class Operation
{
    [Key]
    public int sr { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string Start_Date { get; set; }
    public string End_Date { get; set; }

    public Status status { get; set; }
    public string onTime { get; set; }

    public bool IsConfirmed { get; set; } = false;

}
```

ACTION RESULT

```
    public ActionResult GetCalendarData()
    {  
        return Json(_context.operationes.ToList());
    }
```

CSS and JAVASCRIPT CDNs

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<!-- Font Awesome -->  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />  
<!-- qTip -->  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/jquery.qtip.min.css" />  
<!-- Full Calendar -->  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.9.1/fullcalendar.min.css" />  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.9.1/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print" />  

<!---------------------------------------->

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include moment-->  
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>  
<!-- qTip -->  
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>  
<!-- Full Calendar -->  
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.9.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function ()  
{  
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({  
    header:  
    {  
        left: 'prev,next today',  
        center: 'title',  
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'  
    },  
    buttonText: {  
        today: 'today',  
        month: 'month',  
        week: 'week',  
        day: 'day'  
    },  

    events: function (start, end, timezone, callback)  
    {  
        $.ajax({  
            url: '/Operation/GetCalendarData',  
            type: "GET",  
            dataType: "JSON",  

            success: function (result)  
            {  
                var events = [];  
                $.each(result, function (i, data)  
                {  
                    events.push(  
                   {  
                       title: data.Title,  
                       description: data.Desc,  
                       start: moment(data.Start_Date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),  
                       end: moment(data.End_Date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),  
                       backgroundColor: "#800000",  
                       borderColor: "#FFFFFF"  
                   });  
                });  

                callback(events);  
            }  
        });  
    },  
    allDayDefault: false,
    editable: true,
    droppable: true,

});  
});
```

the final view looks wearied as the calendar doesn't show neither description or title.

Comment: Have you tried this? ```events: '/Operation/GetCalendarData'```

Comment: @KibéM.C No I didn't try it. if I replace url with events it will return null data and the calendar will not render at all.

Comment: What happens when you try that?

Comment: @KibéM.C the calendar disappear.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of fullCalendar?? Version 5 is the latest. It has more features, less bugs, more documentation and better performance. 2.x hasn't been supported for a long time.

Comment: Anyway we'd really need to see your `results` data, we can't debug the code when we can't see the data